# Prevent Circular Dependencies UI error message in Plotly Dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have recursive elements in my Dash program that are well-handled and are never at risk of infinite recursion.
Unfortunately, a box pops up on my app telling me I have a recursion. How do I stop this warning from showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `debug` to False in the main function call

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Dash message about circular dependencies can be suppressed.  It is controlled by the "circular" parameter passed to the DepGraph() function within dash-renderer.  I had the same problem and resolved it by opening dash_renderer.min.js within Python's site-packages/dash_renderer directory, searching for "DepGraph", and replacing the string "this.circular=e&&!!e.circular" by "this.circular=true" just inside the call.
I was led to this solution by postings [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/interdependent-components/8299/5) and [here](https://github.com/jriecken/dependency-graph).

Answer (score 0):

I saw the error while working with two callbacks: one taking a 'value' of an element as input/output, the second only taking the 'value' as output. The error occured when i implemented the second-callback and disappeared when i changed the input from the first one to 'state' - perhaps this helps anyone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31933681)

Comment: hi - the question was how to avoid the warning message and my answer (which worked for me) was to change the input of the second callback from 'input' to 'state'. So in my opinion the post answers the question or gives a hint if it is the same problem. But it's ok.